# Spring Boot - how to call another method outside of the transaction scope

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have the following method:

```
    @Transactional
    public Store handle(Command command) {
        Store store= mapper.map(command.getStoreDto(), Store.class);
        Store persistedStore = storeService.save(store);
        addressService.saveStoreAddress(store, command.getEmployeeId()); //this method is not crucial, should be called independently and in another transaction, without any rollback in case of exception
        return persistedStore;
    }
```

`addressService.saveStoreAddress` is not crucial - when this method will throw any exception, store should be saved anyway (`storeService.save(store);`). What is the best solution in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `saveStoreAddress()` such that it will execute in a new and separate transaction.

To prevent the transaction of the `handle()` will be rollback because of the exception throw from  `saveStoreAddress()` , you also have to try-catch when calling `saveStoreAddress()`.

In the end , it looks something like:

```
@Service
public class AddressService {

   @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void saveStoreAdress(.....){

   }
  
}
```

```
@Transactional
public Store handle(Command command) {
        .......
        try{
          addressService.saveStoreAddress(store, command.getEmployeeId());
        }catch (Exception ex){
           /***
            * handle the exception thrown from saveStoreAddress.
            * If you want the current transaction not rollback just because of the 
            * exception throw from saveStoreAddress(), do not re-throw the exception when 
            * handling this exception 
            */
        }
        return ....;
}
```

Comment: after some research - are you sure that after exception in saveStoreAdress (where AddressService is calling another webservice) there will be no rollback in main transaction?

Comment: I think I will receive: UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Comment: You have to use `Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `saveStoreAdress()`. Also make sure you are not 'self invocation' on the `saveStoreAdress()` such that  `REQUIRES_NEW` will take effect and start a new TX for it